# Write to different files using hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm currently processing about 300 GB of log files on a 10 servers hadoop cluster. My data is being saved in folders named YYMMDD so each day can be accessed quickly.

My problem is that I just found out today that the timestamps I have in my log files are in DST (GMT -0400) instead of UTC as expected. In short, this means that logs/20110926/*.log.lzo contains elements from 2011-09-26 04:00 to 2011-09-27 20:00 and it's pretty much ruining any map/reduce done on that data (i.e. generating statistics).

Is there a way to do a map/reduce job to re-split every log files correctly? From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way using streaming to send certain records in output file A and the rest of the records in output file B.

Here is the command I currently use:

```
/opt/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u1.jar \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=15 -D mapred.output.compress=true \
-D mapred.output.compression.codec=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec \
-mapper map-ppi.php -reducer reduce-ppi.php \
-inputformat com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat \
-file map-ppi.php -file reduce-ppi.php \
-input "logs/20110922/*.lzo" -output "logs-processed/20110922/"
```

I don't know anything about java and/or creating custom classes. I did try the code posted at http://blog.aggregateknowledge.com/2011/08/30/custom-inputoutput-formats-in-hadoop-streaming/ (pretty much copy/pasted what was on there) but I couldn't get it to work at all. No matter what I tried, I would get a "-outputformat : class not found" error.

Thank you very much for your time and help :).

Answer (score 1):

> From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way using streaming to send certain records in output file A and the rest of the records in output file B.

By using a custom [Partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/mapred_tutorial.html#Partitioner), you can specify which key goes to which reducer. By default the [HashPartitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/HashPartitioner.html) is used. Looks like the only other Partitioner Streaming supports is [KeyFieldBasedPartitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/KeyFieldBasedPartitioner.html).

You can find more details about the KeyFieldBasedPartitioner in the context of Streaming [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/streaming.html#Hadoop+Partitioner+Class). You need not know Java to configure the KeyFieldBasedPartitioner with Streaming.

> Is there a way to do a map/reduce job to re-split every log files correctly?

You should be able to write a MR job to re-split the files, but I think Partitioner should solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see how a custom partitioner will solve my problem of saving my data in separate files.

Comment: Using a custom partitioner all the Key1 pairs can be sent to Reduce1 and Key2 pairs can be sent to Reduce2. And each Reducer will create a separate o/p file. So, K1 and K2 will be in separate files as reducer o/p. Based on your requirement you need to partition the keys (in your problem the time) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A custom MultipleOutputFormat and Partitioner seems like the correct way split your data by day.

As the author of that post, sorry that you had such a rough time. It sounds like if you were getting a "class not found" error, there was some issue with your custom output format not being found after you included it with "-libjars".